# Equation: Apple problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm stuck with a question from school, not even the teacher knew this one:

**Question:** Ben goes to the market and pays \$12 for apples (amount unknown), but they were so small that the cashier gave Ben two apples for free. In this way, the price for a dozen apples dropped by exactly \$1.  How many apples did Ben get for \$12?

Comment: If Ben initially bought $n$ apples, what is the per apple price?  After two free apples have been added, what is the new per apple price (as a function of $n$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define

$p$ - regular prize of the apples per apple

$p^*$ - reduced prize of the apples per apple

$n$ - number of apples originally bought

Then we have the following equations:

$n\cdot p=12$ - he payed 12 dollars

$(n+2)\cdot p^*=12$ - he payed 12 dollars for two more apples with the fictional reduced prize

$p\cdot 12 = p^*\cdot12+1$ - the price for a dozen apples is reduced by 1

Solving these equations leads to a quadatric equation which has two possible solutions $n=16$ or $n = -18$.

Please feel free to comment if you like to see the way to actually solve the equations not just the set up.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch

- Let $x$ be the number of apples and $p$ the price per apple.  In this case, $12p$ is the price per dozen.
- Ben received $x+2$ apples at a price of $xp=12$.  Therefore, the price per apple is $\frac{xp}{x+2}$.  The cost for a dozen is now $\frac{12xp}{x+2}$.
- The $\$1$ price drop means that
  $$
  12p=\frac{xp}{x+2}+1
  $$

Now, combine this equation with $xp=12$ and solve.  Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Let the original price of each apple be x.

Let $n$ be the number of apples Ben got before getting the $2$ apples for free.

$\begin{equation}\label{eq:a}\tag{1}\therefore nx=\$12\end{equation}$

Now Ben got $n+2$ apples.

$\therefore$ The new price per apple will be $\dfrac{12}{n+2}=x'(say)$

given that $12x-12x'=1$ (difference given is $\$1$)

Now from equation $(1)$ $x=\dfrac{12}{n}$

solving we get $n=16$